# customize each individual hotkey

Tags: vb.net

A little help, I want to make a customize each individual hotkey.
but I have a problem if my app is not focused hotkeys does not work
any idea?

```
Public Class Form1


Private KeySelections As New Dictionary(Of String, Keys)


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    KeySelections.Add("Home", Keys.Home)
    KeySelections.Add("Insert", Keys.Insert)

    ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(KeySelections.Keys.ToArray)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message, ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean

    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1 Then 


        Dim hotkey As Keys = KeySelections.Item(ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)

        If keyData = hotkey Then 
            Me.Timer1.Enabled = Not Me.Timer1.Enabled    
            If Timer1.Enabled Then
                Label1.Text = "Timer 1 On"
            Else
                Label1.Text = "Timer 1 Off"
            End If
        End If

    End If

    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook into the `User32` Windows library to capture keypresses.

Place this at the top of your code, below your `Import`s but within your module:

```
Public Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Int32) As Int16
```

You can then use `GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.[key])` to get the state of your specific key. Generally if `True`, the key is pressed down.